# If $x \in \cap_{n=1}^\infty I^n$, then $x \in xI$.

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, noetherian

I was looking at a proof in one of my course notes and I saw the following statement, where we assume that $I$ is an ideal in a Noetherian ring $R$:

If $x \in \cap_{n=1}^\infty I^n$, then $x \in xI$.

We of course know that $I$ is finitely generated and hence, so are all the $I^n$ but I don't know how you can then conclude that statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $N = \cap_{i=1}^\infty I^n$, since $R$ is Noetherian, $N$ is a finitely generated $R$-module, then [Artin-Rees lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Rees_lemma) says $IN=N$ (set $M=R$ in Wikipedia notations).

Therefore by [Nakayama's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama%27s_lemma) (Statement 1 in Wikipedia) there exists $r\in R$ such that $r-1 \in I$ and $rN=0$. In particular for $x\in N$, $x = x(1-r) \in xI$.

Comment: Is it trivial to assume that IM = M?

Comment: I would have thought that $IM=M$ is the hard part. The only proof I know is to use Artin-Rees.

Comment: @Mohan  Yes, my carelessness and you're right. Proving $M\subset IM$ is indeed non-trivial.